# Could someone explain gtk2hs drag and drop to me, the listDND.hs demo just isn't doing it for me?

Tags: haskell, drag-and-drop, gtk2hs

As the title says, I just don't get DND (or rather I understand the concept and I understand the order of callbacks, I just don't understand how to setup DND for actual usage.) I'd like to say that I've done DND stuff before in C, but considering I never really got that working...

So I'm trying (and mostly succeeding, save DND) to write a text editor (using gtksourceview, because it has built in code highlighting.) Reasons are below if you want them. Anyways, there's not really a good DND demo or tutorial available for gtk2hs (listDND.hs just doesn't translate well in my head.) 
So what I'm asking is for code that demonstrates simple DND on a window widget (for example.) Ideally, it should accept drops from other windows (such as Thunar) and print out the information in string form. I think I can take it from there...

---

Reasons:
I'm running a fairly light weight setup, dwm and a few gtk+2 programs. I really don't want to have to pull in gtk+3 to get the current gedit from the repos (Arch Linux.) Currently, I'm using geany for all of my text editing needs, however, geany is a bit heavy for editing config files. Further, geany doesn't care for my terminal of choice (st;) so I don't even get the benefit of using it as an IDE. Meaning I'd like a lightweight text editor with syntax highlighting. I could configure emacs or vim or something, but that seems to me to be more of a hack then a proper solution. Thus my project was born. It's mostly working (aside from DND, all that's left is proper multi-tab support.) 
Admittedly, I could probably work this out if I wrote it in C, but there isn't that much state in a text editor so Haskell's been working fine with almost no need for mutable variables.

Comment: Why don't you just download and compile Gedit 2.28?

Comment: Can you make the question a bit more concrete? Drag-n-drop is a big topic to try to explain all in one go, yet even so [there are lots of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=gtk+drag+drop) already available.

Comment: @ptomato 
because I don't want to. Besides I probably don't have all the dependencies for gedit 2.28. The point isn't so much that there are solutions so much as I've already written a 90% solution and I want to complete it.

Comment: @Daniel
gtk2hs has slightly different requirements than standard gtk dnd callbacks. The problem i.m having is that I don't know how to get the data fro. The drag with gtk2hs (as I said, I could probably work it out in C, but I'm not using C.) as for a concrete problem, I gave one: display drag data from thunar.

Comment: @TomCarstens The [dragDataReceived](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/latest/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-Drag.html#v:dragDataReceived) signal gives access to the data associated with a drop. I learned this by looking through [this tutorial](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove/DragNDropTutorial) (one of the top few hits on my search above) and then doing a [Hoogle search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=receive+%2Bgtk).

Comment: None of those are sufficient. Even if I try to set the targetFlags to accept drags from other applications, nothing is displayed (drag-drop never happens.) I assure you, I've done my research. I'm aware of all the documentation and it simply isn't sufficient to write any cross app DND (and I'm not interested in DND within a single app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [tutorial I linked](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove/DragNDropTutorial) and [the gtk2hs documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/latest/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-General-Drag.html), I have written the following minimal application that receives text. I will add it to the gtk2hs demos directory shortly.

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main = do
    initGUI
    w <- windowNew
    l <- labelNew $ Just "drag here lol"
    onDestroy w mainQuit
    containerAdd w l
    dragDestSet w [DestDefaultMotion, DestDefaultDrop] [ActionCopy]
    dragDestAddTextTargets w
    w `on` dragDataReceived $ \dc pos id ts -> do
        s <- selectionDataGetText
        liftIO . putStrLn $ case s of
            Nothing -> "didn't understand the drop"
            Just s  -> "understood, here it is: <" ++ s ++ ">"
    widgetShowAll w
    mainGUI
```

I have no idea whether thunar offers text as one of its selection formats, but if not, the formats it does offer are surely documented somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just needed some confidence. Since I only tested against thunar, I didn't realize that I was doing it right. Off I go to look through thunar's docs...

Comment: That was easy enough. Thunar passes a uri. So all I needed to do was change dragDestAddTextTargets to dragDestAddURITagets and selectionDataGetText to selectionDataGetURI... Which I could have sworn I tried before, but it works now (so I guess it doesn't matter.)