# In Haskell, how can you drag and drop tree view node between tree views in gtk2hs (Gtk3)?

Tags: haskell, drag-and-drop, treeview, gtk3, gtk2hs

I have been trying to figure out how to drag a tree node (maintaining its path) between tree views on a single gtk application window.

If I have the following in a TreeView...

> - One
>
>   - A
>
>     - item 1A
>   - B
>
>     - item 1B
> - Two
>
>   - A
>
>     - item 2A

How can I drag 'item 1A' to another TreeView on the same window to get the following TreeView...

> - One
>
>   - A
>
>     - item 1A

I have attempted to follow the `ListDND.hs` example in the demos directory of the gtk2hs source (which is very helpful); however, since I am using gtk3 the API has changed enough to make it not seem to be perfectly applicable.

I have seen the answer here: [gtk2hs dnd explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966397/could-someone-explain-gtk2hs-drag-and-drop-to-me-the-listdnd-hs-demo-just-isnt)

I thought about just using a string by putting the tree path and node text into a tuple and then calling `show` on the tuple and passing that as the selection in the `treeDragDestDragDataReceived` callback in the `DragDestIface` interface...but I can't seem to get that callback to be called.

I did see the line about the Gtk bug in the `ListDND.hs` file.  So i tried including the following line in my own code but it didn't seem to work:

```
tl <- targetListNew                       
treeViewEnableModelDragDest treeView tl []
```

...Where `treeView` is my drag source.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.